# Angle of circular droplet

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, angle

I am trying to find the angle $\theta$ of the following droplet:

[image: Droplet pic]

I think using $\tan$ is the right way to go, and I thought of using it on the  angle formed by the line $r$ and $b$. However, that requires that I can relate it to $\theta$, which isn't clear to me is necessarily the case. I'd be happy to get some help or a push in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: Try considering $\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The tangent line to a circle is perpendicular to the radius on the intersecting point.

Comment: I get $\pi/2 + \arctan[(h-r)/(b/2)]$, do you agree with this?

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the possible ways. There are two other ways in which you only depend on $h$ and $r$ or $b$ and $r$ respectively (can you find them?).

Comment: @Billy Jean: Yep. $ \pi/2 + \cos^ {-1} \dfrac{b}{2r}  $